# Где ошибка, как будет правильно?

Tags: php, mysql

Задача, у меня пользователи, их надо найти по имени, фамилию и вывести с ссылкой на страницу в виде "page.php?id=123". А он у меня выводит только ошибку "Поиск не осуществлен. Код ошибки:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'surname LIKE '%123%' OR name,surname LIKE '%123%' LIMIT 100' at line 1"

```
 <?
   echo "<p>По вашему запросу:";

    if (isset($_POST['keyword'])) {$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];}

    $keyword = trim($keyword);// убираются лишние пробелы из начала и конца строки
    $keyword = stripslashes($keyword); //удаляет экранирование символов
    $keyword = htmlspecialchars($keyword); // заменяет html теги на коды
    echo "<b>$keyword</b>";

    $search_query = "SELECT id, name, surname FROM users WHERE name,surname LIKE '%".strtoupper($keyword)."%' OR name,surname LIKE '%".strtoupper($keyword)."%' LIMIT 100"; // table - это ваша таблица, где надо искать
    $query = mysql_query($search_query); // Здесь непосредственно происходит поиск

     if(!$query)
     {
    echo "<p class='text'>Поиск не осуществлен. Код ошибки:</p>";
    echo exit(mysql_error());
     }
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
  {
  $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query);

      do
      {
      printf("<p><a class ='post_link' href='page.php?id=%s'>%s</a><span class='post_view'> --> Просмотров: %s</span></p>",$myrow["id"],$myrow["name"],$myrow["surname"]); // здесь делаем ссылку где находится данная информация.

       }while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($query));
  } else echo "<p>Ничего не найдено.";

 ?>
```

Comment: Конструирование запроса вручную конкатенацией со строками, полученными из запроса — открытые настежь ворота для любого script kiddie[.](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)

Comment: @VladD, для начала и это хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишут же:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax

То есть основная ошибка в том, что вы взялись писать код, не почитав справочное руководство по mysql даже самого начального уровня... Откуда вы взяли, что так - правильно, самостоятельно придумали?

```
WHERE name,surname LIKE '%что-то%'
```

Но даже если отвлечься от неправильного синтаксиса, что вы хотели сказать, поставив по обе части от OR **одинаковые** условия?

```
name,surname LIKE '%keyword%' 
    OR 
name,surname LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: Блин, извините, копипаст, теперь все нормально =)